# C Warning "format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int"

Tags: c, warnings

I want to fill up these arrays with a string and some numbers, but can't really seem to figure out why I cannot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct students{
char name[30];
int points[10];
int absences[10];
};

int main()
{
int i, n;
printf("Declare the number of students: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

struct students stud[n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &stud[i].name);
    printf("Points: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud[i].points);
    printf("Absences: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud[i].absences);
}


for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", stud[i].name);
    printf("%d\n", stud[i].points);
    printf("%d\n", stud[i].absences);

}


}
```

This is the warning i get:

warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[30]' [-Wformat=]

```
     scanf("%s", &stud[i].name);
```

feladat1.c:21:15: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)[10]' [-Wformat=]

```
     scanf("%d", &stud[i].points);
```

feladat1.c:23:15: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)[10]' [-Wformat=]

```
     scanf("%d", &stud[i].absences);
```

feladat1.c:30:16: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]

```
     printf("%d\n", stud[i].points);
```

feladat1.c:31:16: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]

```
     printf("%d\n", stud[i].absences);
```

Comment: Change this `struct students{
char name[30];
int points[10];
int absences[10];
};` to `struct students{
char name[30];
int points;
int absences;
};` And this `scanf("%s", &stud[i].name);` --> `scanf("%s", stud[i].name);` since `name` itself an address hence `&` is not required.

Comment: Instead of having magical numbers like `30` and `10` in your code, define constants that represent them. This helps avoid mistakes when you change several instances to a new value, but forget some others. C is a very unforgiving language, it will do *exactly* what you ask, so you need to go out of your way to be careful and not set yourself up for problems.

Comment: @Achal Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

1. In `struct students`, `int points[10];` should be `int points;`, `int absences[10];` should be `int absences;`
2. The line `scanf("%s", &stud[i].name);` should be `scanf("%s", stud[i].name);`

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct students{
    char name[30];
    int points;
    int absences;
};

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    printf("Declare the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct students *stud = malloc(sizeof(struct students) * n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", stud[i].name);
        printf("Points: ");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].points);
        printf("Absences: ");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].absences);
    }


    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", stud[i].name);
        printf("%d\n", stud[i].points);
        printf("%d\n", stud[i].absences);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stating what code should be does not answer the question, because it does not explain what was wrong or why it was wrong, nor does it explain why the new code is correct nor what the difference is.